# Sitecore CMS migration to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sitecore

Is there any documentation on moving a Sitecore CMS into SharePoint? I see a lot of SharePoint to Sitecore, but that is not the case for me. Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to be much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You might start by looking [how Sitecore stores data in SQL Server](https://making-it-faster.blog/2020/01/01/case-study-database-optimization/), basics:

- Item definition (ID, name, parent) lives in `Items` table
- Item fields (actual data) live in `Versioned`/`Unversioned`/`Shared` field tables
- Blobs are stored in `Blobs` table; blobId is referenced from fields table
- Blobs might be stored on File System, rare case these days....

Alternatively you could use [Sitecore item API](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/sitecore-item-api.html) to access data in Sitecore form.

Next, you could sketch the way (data struct) you want Sitecore data to flow into Sharepoint.